# IOS UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am actually doing a simple app, which is Mememe kind. My problem is using the `UIActivityViewController`, when trying to save it, share it, etc. But why does not it happen here? I guess this is because of passing an empty image. But really I don't know how to solve it. Can anyone help me please?
Here is the code:

```
@IBAction func savingMyImage(sender: AnyObject) {
    let image = UIImage()
    let controller = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [image], applicationActivities: nil)
    presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)

    controller.completionWithItemsHandler = { (activity: String?, completed: Bool, items: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
      if completed {
        self.save()
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
      }
    }
}
```

Thanks to eveyone.

Comment: doesn't it be `self.presentViewController()` ??

Comment: @MrugeshTank, no. Swift doesn't require explicit `self` call.

Comment: @rkyr, I know that. But you didn't mention that what kind of problem you are facing.

Comment: the controller is not presenting? / item is not displaying in controller? / image is not shared on selected item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I try to repeat your problem: create new project (XCode7 iOS SDK 9), add button and copy-paste your code. Everything is work fine. So check if your method being called. Setup breakpoint to begin of your method and push the button.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I ran this on the iPad 2 and iPad Air simulators and got the error below.  I do not need to add the popover line for iPhone 6

ViewControllerExp[1911:87261] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'UIPopoverPresentationController (<_UIAlertControllerActionSheetRegularPresentationController: 0x7f94a24c3a80>) should have a non-nil sourceView or barButtonItem set before the presentation occurs.'

This code worked for me:

```
    let image = UIImage()

    let controller = UIActivityViewController(activityItems:[image], applicationActivities:nil)

    //had to add this line to get it to work for the iPad simulator; 
    //it is not necessary for the iPhone 6 simulator
    controller.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view

    self.presentViewController(controller, animated:true, completion:nil)
```